# Recurrence relation for pairing off $2n$ people

Tags: recurrence-relations

I know the answer is supposed to be 
$$a_{2n} = (2n-1) a_{2n-2}$$
Can someone please explain why shouldn't be having $\binom{2n}{2}$ in place of $2n-1$?

Doesn't it matter which two people are paired off out of the $2n$ people and hence generating a different case each time for the remaining $(2n-2)$ people?

Comment: I don't know where I'm wrong, but I keep getting $a_{2n+2} = a_{2n} + 2n(2n-1) a_{2n-2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the problem of pairing $2n$ people AND label one of these pairs.  Then the number of ways is
$$b_{2n}=\binom{2n}{2}a_{2n-2}$$
This is what we enumerate when in your formula we have $\binom{2n}{2}$ in place of $2n-1$.

Since there are $n$ possible pairs, we may "unlabel" the labelled pair by dividing by $n$:
$$a_{2n}=\frac{b_{2n}}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n}{2}a_{2n-2}=(2n-1)a_{2n-2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that you have people numbered from $1$ through $2n$. First you decide who gets paired with person $1$; there are $2n-1$ ways to do that. Once you’ve done that, you’re left with $2n-2$ people, who can be paired up in $a_{2n-2}$ different ways. Thus, $a_{2n}=(2n-1)a_{2n-2}$.

Comment: Yeah, But what if we paired off the second person with someone ? The remaining 2n-2 people will possibly constitute a different set right ? So shouldn't that be accounted for ? 
If the question was about climbing stairs or something alike and 'sequential' in nature, I would have been able to make sense out of such arguments since there won't be any possibility of climbing step #2 before having already climbed step #1 in the process.

Comment: @PSuniq: No: even if you start by pairing up the second person, at some point you're going to form a pair that includes the first person. Thus, you're going to end up with one of the arrangements that I counted in my answer: you don't get anything new.

Comment: Alright, Person 1 would only have 2n-1 options for a partner and eventually be paired only in those many number of ways and hence the factor of 2n-1 makes sense. :)